# Передача данных из js в чанк FormIt

Tags: modx, jquery, formit

Добрый день, знатоки! У меня вопрос к вам, почему не работает такой код. В скрипте в чанке шапки сайта подключаю такой скрипт:

```
$(".kol_vo_comps" ).text("проверка1");
$(".kol_vo_servers" ).text("проверка2");
$(".cost_zakaz" ).text("проверка3");
```

Вызываю сниппет FormIt: [[!FormIt? &hooks=`email,redirect` &emailTpl=`handlerTpl` &emailSubject=`Сообщение` &emailTo=`тут_мой_ящик` &redirectTo=`1`]]

Как видно, вызывается чанк handlerTpl, в нем прописаны те блоки, которые я заполнил в jquery скрипте:

```
<dd><span class="kol_vo_comps"></span></dd>
<dt>Количество серверов:</dt>
<dd><span class="kol_vo_servers"></span></dd>
<dt>Стоимость заказа:</dt>
<dd><span class="cost_zakaz"></span></dd>
```

По идее, туда должны попадать значения, но не попадают. Почему? Когда пишу такой скрипт в песочнице, то все работает. Это что, особенность ModX или компонента FormIt?

А тут все работает: http://jsfiddle.net/51z4u4uo/1/

Comment: Что, никто не знает ответа на этот вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS может только заполнить поля у пользователя в браузере. Отсылкой заполненной формы занимается непосредственно браузер, используя методы передачи информации на сервер. Если на сервере ты не можешь получить какие-то переменные, то проверь в инспекторе отправляемые из браузера данные и на сервере - принимаемые.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ), правда запоздалый, решил уже сам. Но все равно спасибо)